# API console always queries Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

On any Stack Exchange site (well, I tried [Super User](http://api.superuser.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids) (trilogy), [Unix](http://api.unix.stackexchange.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids) (SE-2.0 launched) and [SFF](http://api.scifi.stackexchange.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids) (SE-2.0 beta)), the console (“Show Console” button) in the 1.1 API queries `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/…` instead of the appropriate site (`http://api.superuser.com/1.1/…`, etc).

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is by design, simply because it is intended as an example and not a comprehensive testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

For now at least, its intentional that all API testing pages hit Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow has much more data to play around with, after all, which is the important part.

Comment: Since this has now been implemented, I've marked this question as [status-complete]. Please feel free to make a correction if I'm wrong.